# Mongo DB throwing NullPointerException on FindIterable iteration

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous

I am retrieving the documents from the MongoDB with the collection.find().into() to generate the documents. The following is the code -

```
    List<Document> scrapingInformation = new LinkedList<>();

    database.getCollection(scrapingInformationByClientidJobid)
        .find(and(eq("clientId", clientId), eq("jobId", jobId)))
        .into(scrapingInformation, (res, ex) -> {
            System.out.println("Exception while iterating over the 
                finditerable and adding to document list: " + ex.getMessage());
        });

    System.out.println("Total populated documents in list: " + scrapingInformation.size());
```

Data is there in the database. The `find()` method reads that data as well. The problem comes when I try to iterate on the data.
I tried iterating over the FindIterable as well. There was also the NullPointerException.

The version I installed is 4.0 and driver 3.8.1. To remove the possibility of version conflict I downgraded to 3.6.1 and still, there is the problem.

**Update -** The cause of this exception might be the async behavior of the driver. The `foreach()` or `into()` might start iterating over the result from Mongo DB and the method leaves its scope. And hence the list is with size 0.

What could be the cause of this exception?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I am using the async driver which is not suitable to read the data from DB and use it for purposes, not including the data streaming. So, switched to the sync driver and now it is working fine.

P.S. I thought of deleting this question but kept it intact just in case someone has the same issue, s/he might find the solution.